# Extract substring numbers from string pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list like this

```
lis=["proc_movieclip1_0.450-16.450.wav", "proc_movieclip1_17.700-23.850.wav", "proc_movieclip1_25.800-29.750.wav"]
```

I've converted into df by

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.DataFrame(mylist2)
dfs.columns=['path']
dfs
```

so dfs look like this

```
      path
0   proc_movieclip1_0.450-16.450.wav
1   proc_movieclip1_17.700-23.850.wav
2   proc_movieclip1_25.800-29.750.wav
```

I just wanto extract this num range in string as a new column as follows

```
range 

0.450-16.450

17.700-23.850

25.800-29.750
```

what I've tried.

```
dfs.path.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

output

```
    0
0   1
1   1
2   1
```

Also tried

```
dfn = dfs.assign(path = lambda x: x['path'].str.extract('(\d+)'))
```

I got same output as above...Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a more complex regex here:

```
dfs['path'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

output:

```
               0
0   0.450-16.450
1  17.700-23.850
2  25.800-29.750
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LUfjMh/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're unfamiliar with regex, you would want to use [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method:

```py
def Extractor(string):
    num1, num2 = string.split('_')[-1][:-4].split('-')
    return (float(num1), float(num2))
```

Result:

```
>>> Extractor('proc_movieclip1_0.450-16.450.wav')
(0.45, 16.45)
```

Lambda one-liner:

```py
lambda x: tuple([float(y) for y in x.split('_')[-1][:-4].split('-')])
```